# How to save dynamically-added input fields to a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, input, hash, textfield, parameters

I'm using MongoMapper and Rails 4.

For a `Campaign` model, I'd like to have an attribute `custom_payouts` which is a type of `Hash`: `{'Username123': 0.80, 'other_guy', 0.25}`.

I would like to iterate through it on the "edit campaign" page and dynamically fill the input boxes:

[image]

I'm struggling with finding a good way of transitioning two separate `<input>` boxes (added by javascript upon user's request) to exactly that format.

I need a way to turn two `<input>` tags into a key / value pair for a hash but I can't seem to figure out how to make it so that incoming `params` are in the right format.

In other words, here's what I want to see:

```
{
   "utf8":"✓",
   "authenticity_token":"whatever==",
   "campaign":{
      "name":"Test Campaign",
      "custom_payouts": {
        "Username123": 0.25,
        "other_guy": 0.80,
      },
      "controller":"campaigns",
      "action":"create"
   }
}
```

What names should my `input` tags be equal to have this result?

Edit: The difficulty seems to be that the name for one of the tags needs to be its value by the time the form is submitted.

Comment: could you describe your model and the form generation view?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady The campaign model simply has a `Hash` field (custom_payouts), and a `String` field (name) for now. Forget about anything else in the form generation view though: 

I just want to know how to take the contents of those two `input` tags and add them to the campaign's custom_payouts attribute without having to do some param manipulations in the controller. Hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
<%= form_for @campaign do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name, "name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :"custom_payouts[][:username]", "Username" %>
  <%= text_field_tag "campaign[custom_payouts][][:username]" %>

  <%= f.label :"custom_payouts[][:percentage]", "Percentage" %>
  <%= text_field_tag "campaign[custom_payouts][][:percentage]" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: undefined method `custom_payouts[][:username]' for #<Campaign:0x007fbf33e3d060>

Comment: well i guess you can create it manually, but i really didn't want to do that, try replacing each `f.text_field` with `text_field_tag`

Comment: could you tell me the working version so i could fix my answer

Comment: %td= text_field_tag("campaign[custom_payouts][][name]", name, class: 'form-control') %td= text_field_tag("campaign[custom_payouts][][percentage]", percentage, class: 'form-control')

Comment: This doesn't result in exactly the output I wanted but close enough to what I wanted so it's all good